# Properly make a BETWEEN clause in DjangoORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

Im having problem querying the desired result in my database using `DjangoORM`.

Here is my model.

```
class HeatWatchList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                   related_name='watchlist_users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    heat = models.OneToOneField(Heat, related_name='heat_watch_list', 
                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    next_date_from = models.DateTimeField()
    next_date_to = models.DateTimeField()
```

I would like to get all record where today's date is BETWEEN `next_date_from` and `next_date_to` fields.

And i can easily do this in raw sql:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    farm_management_db.heat_heatwatchlist
WHERE
    DATE(now()) BETWEEN DATE(next_date_from) AND DATE(next_date_to);
```

**This is what i tried so far but i ain't getting any records:**

```
HeatWatchList.objects.filter(
                next_date_from__date__gte=datetime.now().date(),
                next_date_to__date__lte=datetime.now().date()
            )
```

Comment: datetime.now() is not 2017-01-23

Comment: sorry about that it is `now()`

Comment: does this revised raw query produce any results?

Comment: well the ORM query produces a query similar to your raw query. A few lines of sample data might hel[

Comment: It doenst procude anything i just remove the `__date` and fixed it like `next_date_from__lte` and `next_date_to__gte` to be working, but it include the time query i dont have idea how to exclude the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the following code instead(by removing the __date):

```
HeatWatchList.objects.filter(
                next_date_from__gte=datetime.now().date(),
                next_date_to__lte='2017-01-23'
            )
```

Comment: this one partially solved it but i have a model.DateTimeField so when i query i would like to exclude the time.

Comment: It should be next_date_from__lte and next_date_to__gte to be working properly but thq query include the time.

Comment: A work around for this, is to use Dajngo DateField instead of DateTimeField, or, you can construct the compared value as a DatetimeField with "T00:00:00' and "23:59:59"

Comment: oh that sad, but i think i'll stick to this it is the best way to implement this approach. but would you please change the `next_date_from__gte=datetime.now().date(),
                next_date_to__lte='2017-01-23'` to  `next_date_from__lte=datetime.now().date(),
                next_date_to__gte=datetime.now().date()` instead? its working now

Comment: unless change the above code to `next_date_from__lte=datetime.now().date(), next_date_to__gte=datetime.now().date()` it's work partially

Answer (score 1):

You can do this(by removing the `__date`) and use `datetime.combine`

```
from datetime import  datetime, time

HeatWatchList.objects.filter(
                next_date_from__gte=datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), time.min),
                next_date_to__lte=datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), time.max)
            )
```

Comment: this is the same as shady answer

Comment: It is time dependent

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function to your model.

`def is_between_date(self):
    if Timezone.zone() > next_date_from and timezone.zone() < next_date_to: 
        return True 
    return False`